# Next.js _ styles not applying to jQuery append element

Tags: html, jquery, css, next.js

```
import styles from './xyz.module.css'
import $ from 'jquery'

export default function abc () {

const input = '<input type="text" className={styles.input}/>'

const addInput = () => {
$('#add').before(input) }

return(
<div>
<form method="post" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>

<input type="text" className={styles.input}/>

<button className={styles.add} onClick={addInput} id='add'>add</button>

<button type="submit" className={styles.submit}>submit</button>

<form>
</div>
)
}
```

[image: See what is the problem]

I'm not getting the new input field like the previous one. Border, width not applying to the new one appended before add button.

```
const input = '<input type="text"/>'
const addInput = () => {
$('#add').before(input).addClass('input')
```

Still not working.